# What is Google Chrome's blob storage and how to clean it?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, storage

Today I was doing some disk tidying, and I've found that in my home directory (using Ubuntu 20), there is a  `.config` folder taking almost 10GB, I've narrowed it down to this fella:

`/home/someuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/blob_storage` containing files between 5MB-7MB all named with just numbers, but there are almost 1400 of them taking almost 8GB, I tried to output one of those files and it seems it contains some sort of site-related structured data.

What are these files? How to clean them/reduce them? (Preferrably without cleaning All browser data...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a 1 year old question, but answer from Ashok is wrong. Let me tell you why. Blob is a binary large object. In Google Chrome, when you download file from some file sharing website, and they don't use a traditional approach, where file is downloaded right into your downloads, they use mostly blobs. Blobs are by design saved to the browser memory or to the disk when they don't meet certain requirements. So most of the blobs stored in this folder you are talking about are some files you downloaded before. You should be okay deleting the entire directory. However, blobs should be deleted automatically (freed from the memory/disk) by browser after the browser doesn't need them. Some versions of Chrome had an issue, with blobs being persisted, even though they should have been deleted already.

You can read more about the architecture of blobs [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/storage/browser/blob/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

The Blob storage is nothing but your browsing history, cookies and other site data, cached image and files, passwords, auto fill form data for your smooth browser experience.

you can simply clean the relevant items in settings -> privacy and security -> select the items to clean up.

I usually clean up cache and cookies mostly as sometimes the css changes wont get reflected due to cached images and data during web development.

Comment: Hmm interesting, after update of my system and chrome & pc restart the folder was suddenly empty (resp. had 1 empty folder) - but I've remained logged in everywhere - are you sure cookies are there?

Comment: Yes, sessions are stored in browser where as cache and cookies stored in your local storage and cookies will get cleared on restart.

Comment: my point is they are not cleared - since it kept me logged-in everywhere :) - maybe this is a cache for other storages?

Comment: clear cookies in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies to see if you are still logged in.

Answer (score 1):

[Martin Choutka](https://superuser.com/users/1705284/martin-choutka) is correct. You can simply delete the `blob_storage` folder (e.g., mine was located in `C:\Users\franckdernoncourt\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\blob_storage`). It does not contain the browsing history, cookies, passwords, auto fill form data.

---

Example in my case:

[image]

Contents:

[image]

Before removing the `blob_storage` folder:

[image]

None of these numbers changed after removing the `blob_storage` folder.